# If statement doesn't stop execution. C programming

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm very new to this, and i'm trying to create a text based minesweeper.
I want the player to decide how big he want the grid to be.
My problem is, that the if-statement, that should make sure, the user types in a number from 1 to 10 doesn't work. Please have a look.

```
scanf ("%i/%i",&x,&y);
if (0 < x < 11 && 0 < y < 11)
{   
printf ("you have selected %i by %i\n",x,y);
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    {
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++) 
        {
        grid[x][y] = 'O';
        printf ("%c ", grid[x][y]);
        }
    printf ("\n");
    }
}
else
printf ("Wrong gridsize");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C does not support double comparisons like:

> 0 < x < 11

you should write instead

> 0 < x && x < 11.

It may be misleading, because the first statement is syntaxically correct (it compiles), but it does not do what you may believe: check both boundaries like in a mathematical expression (what python does for instance).

It's like if you had written

> (0 < x) < 11

The first binary expression returns a boolean (well, really an int in C, a boolean in C++). This boolean once casted to int is 0 or 1, always below 11, henceforth the expression is always true.

Of course the same is true for checking y boundaries. Now you should be able to fix the problem by yourself.

Comment: Who sad c does not support it...

Try this

if(9 < 6 == 0)
   printf("yes");
   else
   printf("No");

Comment: It is syntaxically correct but it does not do what you believe. In your example the left comparizon returns a boolean, the second comparizon compares this boolean to zero. There is no ternary operator other than ?: in C. All others are binary operators.

Comment: @Indra Yadav: is it a joke on ambiguity of the word *support* or are you not a C programmer ?

Comment: if not support then how above code is working.. i'll be glad if you will explain double comparisons in C.. and explain both 0 < x < 11 and 9 < 6 == 0

Comment: I did. Just read the answer. These expressions are treated as two individual statements from left to right. By the way the second one (9 < 6 == 0) is meaningless from a mathematical point of view, it has a meaning only in a context where 9 < 6 is first evaluated, and the result is then compared to zero (and zero means "False").

Comment: yeah you are right... thats the same what i know... i just opposed your word "does not support".. because it support the syntax but in another way.. you can use it as you logic.. it may depends on your variable type, if  your all variables are bool then it will work perfectly

Comment: @Indra Yadav: what I mean is that is won't ever be a ternary operator checking some mathematical interval like what Python support. That's merely two independent binary expressions and usual operator precedence rules apply. That a program is compiling means nothin. For instance it compiles if you use '=' instead of '==' inside an if condition, but it will still be an assignment, not ever become a comparison. Same logic applies here.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement has to be like

```
if ((x > 0 && x < 11) && (y > 0 && y < 11))
```

Answer (score 1):

you have written wrong `if statement`.
Here is correct form.

```
if ((x > 0 && x < 11) && (y > 0 && y < 11))
```

Here are the `relational operators`

```
>     greater than              5 > 4 is TRUE
<     less than                 4 < 5 is TRUE
>=    greater than or equal     4 >= 4 is TRUE
<=    less than or equal        3 <= 4 is TRUE
==    equal to                  5 == 5 is TRUE
!=    not equal to              5 != 4 is TRUE
```

C does **not support** `double comparisons`.

Answer (score 1):

In your scanf statement remove / operator change it to

```
scanf ("%i%i",&x,&y);
```

And what your if statement is doing is what you expect to do

```
if (0 < x < 11 && 0 < y < 11)
```

first when you enter the value x and y (x = 4 and  y = 6)

It checks if x is greater than 0 (which is true ) so 1 is substituted in place of **0 < x**

now its something like this for compiler **1 < 11** 
 next it checks that which is also true 
similarly for y whichever value you enter will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 < x < 11
```

means
    (0 < x)<11. If x is 5, 0 < x will be 1 (true). Next evaluation will be 1 < 11, that will be true so the result is true.

But, if x = 20, 0<20 is 1, 1<11 is true as well, but you would expect a false result.